# Pandas groupby(...).mean() lost keys

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe `rounds` (which was the result of deleting a column from another dataframe) with the following structure (can't post pics, sorry):

```
----------------------------
|type|N|D|NATC|K|iters|time|
----------------------------
rows of data
----------------------------
```

I use `groupby` so I can then get the mean of the groups, like so:

```
rounds = results.groupby(['type','N','D','NATC','K','iters'])
results_mean = rounds.mean()
```

I get the means that I wanted but I get a problem with the keys. The `results_mean` dataframe has the following structure:

```
----------------------------
|    | | |    | |     |time|
|type|N|D|NATC|K|iters|    |
----------------------------
rows of data
----------------------------
```

The only key recognized is `time` (I executed `results_mean.keys()`).

What did I do wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post raw input data, code to reproduce your issue and desired output into your question it's unclear what your problem is

Comment: The statement *"The only key recognized is `time`"* doesn't mean anything in pandas. pandas only knows about columns, and index(es). In your case you have one column `time`, and an index, which is a MultiIndex (`'type','N','D','NATC','K','iters'`), since you grouped-by multiple columns.

Comment: **If you want to see the columns of `results_mean`, do `results_mean.columns` not `results_mean.keys()`**. Don't start confusing SQL terminology like 'key' with Python, where 'keys' are things a dict has. That will only multiply confusion. Stick to using the standard terms 'index', 'MultiIndex', 'columns'. Don't try to call `.keys()` on dataframes to get their `.columns` attribute. (Now, dicts do support `.keys()` method, and pandas sometimes uses dicts under-the-hood to implement grouping and so on. But don't try to call `.keys()` on dataframes to get their `.columns` attribute)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your aggregated data, `time` is the only column. The other ones are indices.

`groupby` has a parameter `as_index`. [From the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> **as_index** : *boolean, default True*
>
> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index. Only relevant for DataFrame input. as_index=False is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output

So you can get the desired output by calling

```
rounds = results.groupby(['type','N','D','NATC','K','iters'], as_index = False)
results_mean = rounds.mean()
```

Or, if you want, you can always convert indices to keys [by using `reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). Using

```
rounds = results.groupby(['type','N','D','NATC','K','iters'])
results_mean = rounds.mean().reset_index()
```

should have the desired effect as well.

Comment: I'll try as soon as I can, but seems spot on. I had read the doc but didn't fully understand what it meant.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem of losing the `dataframes's` keys due to the use of the `group_by()` function and the answer I found for that problem was to convert the Dataframe into a CSV file then read this file.