# groupby.mean() is not returning a correctly formatted dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

my original data frame is in this structure:

```
     Survived                                               Name     Sex   Age
0           0                            Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male  22.0
1           1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...  female  38.0
2           1                             Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  26.0
3           1       Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)  female  35.0
4           0                           Allen, Mr. William Henry    male  35.0
```

but after using thing line of code in order to obtain rate of death by gender:

```
piedf = origindf.groupby(['Sex']).mean()[['Survived']]
display(piedf)
```

the output looks poorly formatted:

```
    Survived
Sex 
female  0.742038
male    0.188908
```

how can i make the dataframe look something like this, where i can easily access the values for sex:

```
      Sex   Survived
0  female   0.742038
1    male   0.188908
```

Comment: What is `display()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas groupby(...).mean() lost keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625531/pandas-groupby-mean-lost-keys). In particular, the last example in the accepted answer.

Comment: Try using `piedf = origindf.groupby(['Sex'], group_keys=False).mean()[['Survived']]`

Comment: You can use `reset_index()` to get DataFrame you want.